# Automatically deploy resource files to Central Administration's App_GlobalResources folder when deploying a solution to a web application

Tags: resource-files, deployment

I'm developing a SharePoint 2010 solution which consists of some web parts and other components. Furthermore the solution needs a application pages in the Central Administration for configuration.

So my solution contains an extra feature which places a  custom actions in the Central Administration menu that links to a application page providing the configuration. The feature has the scope `WebApplication` and uses the Attribute `AutoActivateInCentralAdmin` set to `True` so the feature is automatically activated in the Central Administration when the solution is deployed to a web application. This part of my solution works as expected.

But I've got some issues regarding the resource files which are used by the application pages in the Central Administration as they only get deployed to the `App_GlobalResources` folder of web application the solution was deployed to but not to the `App_GlobalResources` of the Central Administration.

So I'm wondering why to use the `AutoActivateInCentralAdmin` when there is no automatic deployment of the resource files to the `App_GlobalResources` folder of Central Administration.

What is the best way to deploy the resource files to the Central Administrations `App_GlobalResources` folder whenever the solution is deployed to any web application in the farm? Is there an automatic way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever resources are placed in SPHive/CONFIG/AdminResources will be placed in the Central Admin App_GlobalResources folder.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. I mapped the AdminResources folder in my solution and copied my resource files to it. But when I deploy the solution to a web application the resource files don't get copied to the Central Admin App_GlobalResources folder.

Comment: what happens when you run stsadm -o copyappbincontent

Comment: Ah great this works. Is there a pendant to this stsadm statement in the SP object model? So that I could trigger it during feature activation?

Comment: Ok, I did some more research and found out, that stsadm -o copyappbincontent and ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer() (which seems to be the pendant to stsadm -o copyappbincontent in the OM) are only executed on the local server the feature was activated on. So in a farm scenario both have to be call on each web front end server after feature activation. Unfortunately this is no option for me.

Comment: You would need to create a job that runs this code on all front end servers. Your Timer service account will need to be local administrator as well due to Microsoft's rubbish implementation of ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer(). Their code checks if the current user is a local administrator and then runs code that actually doesn't require local admin rights. We ended up writing our own version of ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer() that is automatically scheduled on all servers in the farm. It was a pain, but works very well. It also takes care of web.config changes and breadcrumbs

Comment: Ah ok, I've read about this solution in some blog. So this really seems to be the only way to handle this.

Comment: I have researched this extensively and other than using a regular  Windows Setup Application this is the only way to go.